# Global access to variables and properties for a C# Excel add in

Tags: c#, excel, variables, add-in, global

I am creating an accounting add in for Microsoft Excel using C#.  In this add in, I want to exchange user data between individual forms.  The closest thing I got was:

```
namespace ExcelAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        public void RefreshExcelData()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And...

```
private void btnUploadTestCases_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var addIn = Globals.ThisAddIn;
    addIn.RefreshExcelData();           
}
```

This works to varying degrees of success, and it only allows me to call methods from that class.  It doesn't allow me to access variables or class properties I instantiate within ThisAddIn.cs.  What I need to know is how to initialize data (variables, properties, methods, etc.) such that it can be retrieved from any item in the solution, including my forms.

And for the love of God, keep it simple.  I've spent the better part of a month on MSDN with far too much complications and little success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define a field in the addin (lets call it globalString):

```
namespace ExcelAddIn{       
    public partial class ThisAddIn{
        public static string globalString;
        public void RefreshExcelData(){
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can access the `globalString` variable from another class like this:

```
namespace ExcelAddIn{
   class TestClass {
      public static void SetTheGlobalStringValue(){
         ThisAddIn.globalString = "Global String";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  Can this be applied to forms as well?

Comment: Sure. If they are in the same project you can use them the same way. If you have them in another project you just have to add a reference to your addin project.